# 'Don't care' for a column in SQLite queries?

Tags: python, sqlite

I've got a SQLite query, which depends on 2 variables, gender and hand. Each of these can have 3 values, 2 which actually mean something (so male/female and left/right) and the third is 'all'. If a variable has a value of 'all' then I don't care what the particular value of that column is.

Is it possible to achieve this functionality with a single query, and just changing the variable? I've had a look for a wildcard or don't care operator but haven't been able to find any except for % which doesn't work in this situation.

Obviously I could make a bunch of if statements and have different queries to use for each case but that's not very elegant.

Code:

```
select_sql = """    SELECT * FROM table
                    WHERE (gender = ? AND hand = ?)
             """
cursor.execute(select_sql, (gender_var, hand_var))
```

I.e. this query works if gender_val = 'male' and hand_var = 'left', but not if gender_val or hand_var = 'all'

Comment: you can use `OR` - `(gender = 'male' OR gender = 'all')`

Comment: Sorry I should have made that clearer. In the DB those columns only take the values of gender/male or left/right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indeed do this with a single query. Simply compare each variable to `'all'` *in your query.*

```
select_sql = """  SELECT * FROM table
                  WHERE ((? = 'all' OR gender = ?) AND (? = 'all' OR hand = ?))
             """

cursor.execute(select_sql, (gender_var, gender_var, hand_var, hand_var))
```

Basically, when `gender_var` or `hand_var` is `'all'`, the first part of each `OR` expression is always true, so that branch of the `AND` is always true and matches all records, i.e., it is a no-op in the query.

It might be better to build a query dynamically in Python, however, that has just the fields you actually need to test. It might be noticeably faster, but you'd have to benchmark that to be sure.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I just assumed you would't be able to compare the python variables to 'all' in the SQL statement.

Time shouldn't be too much of a concern as it's not a large DB but will bear that in mind.

Comment: I've always been partial to named placeholders instead of just the qmark style, especially if this scales into a larger project or gets reused.  Also, I love readability.

Comment: @Stu: from SQL's standpoint you're just comparing one string constant to another; by the time `sqlite` sees the query, the values of the Python variables have been substituted into the query so it looks like `'all' = 'all'`.